# The updated meta tags not showing up on social share facebook - backbone.js

Tags: javascript, facebook, backbone.js

My index.html has certain meta tags and in the Backbone view i am trying to update them.

```
    setMetaTags: function (title, description, image) {
    $('meta[property="og:title"]').remove();
    $('head').append('<meta name="og:title" content="' + title + '">');

    $('meta[property="og:description"]').remove();
    $('head').append('<meta name="og:description" content="' + description + '">');

    $('meta[property="og:image"]').remove();
    $('head').append('<meta name="og:image" itemprop="image" content="' + image + '">');

    //Twitter meta tags
    $('meta[property="twitter:title"]').remove();
    $('head').append('<meta name="twitter:title" content="' + title + '">');

    $('meta[property="twitter:description"]').remove();
    $('head').append('<meta name="twitter:description" content="' + description + '">');

    $('meta[property="twitter:image"]').remove();
    $('head').append('<meta name="twitter:image" content="' + image + '">');
},
```

**Inside render:**

```
 this.setMetaTags(
            this.profileData.profile_name, this.profileData.profile_description, this.profileData.profile_image_url
        );
```

Please help

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing

Comment: that other thread is about polymer, but the question is the same and there are plenty of others about the topic. dynamic og tags are not supported.

Comment: @luschn are there any alernatives to this.

Comment: no, you have to make sure that the og tags are accessible without javascript. for example, by using serverside rendering for SPAs.